# Firebase Async/Await DeprecationWarning: Unhandled promise rejections are deprecated

Tags: firebase, firebase-realtime-database, promise, async-await, google-cloud-functions

I am trying to create a simple connection to my Firebase Realtime-Database using Functions with Async/Await to reduce code and even thou I wrap the code using try/catch, it still throws the following error.

```
exports.createBlogPost = functions.https.onRequest(async (req, res) => {
  try {
    cors(req, res, () => { });
    const response = req.body;
    response.createDate = new Date();
    const snapshot = await admin.database().ref(BLOG_POSTS).push(response);
    console.log("SNAP", snapshot.getKey());
    response.id = snapshot.getKey();
    res.send(response);
  } catch (e) {
    res.status(500).send(e);
  }
});
```

It creates the instance in the database but I receive the following warning:

```
info: SNAP -LdnpewpwEz9EOkAA05H

error: (node:13656) UnhandledPromiseRejec: Unhandled promise rejections are deprecated. 
In the future, promise rejectiontionWarning: Unhandled promise rejection. Node.js process with a non-zero exit code. 
This error originated either by throwingon completed successfully inside of an async function without a catch block, or by rejecting a promise which was not handled with .catch(). (rejection id: 1)(node:13656) 
[DEP0018] DeprecationWarning: Unhandled promise rejections are deprecated. 
In the future, promise rejections that are not handled will terminate the Node.js process with a non-zero exit code.info: Execution took 1035 ms, user function completed successfullyerror: Function worker killed by signal: SIGTERM
```